# drawing line with arrow between 2 buttons

Tags: android, button, draw

I have 12 lines I've created using the following class

```
public class LineView extends View {
   private Paint paint = new Paint();
   private PointF pointA,pointB;

//    private void init() {
//        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
//    }

    public LineView(Context context) {
        super(context);
     //   init();
    }

    public LineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
     //   init();
    }

    public LineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       // init();
    }


    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int color = R.color.GradientStart;
        paint.setColor(color);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        //canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(pointA.x, pointA.y, pointB.x, pointB.y, paint);

    }
    public void setPointA(PointF point){
            pointA=point;
}
    public void setPointB(PointF point){
        pointB=point;
    }
    public void draw(){
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

}
```

Instead of lines I what lines with arrows. The line with arrow will be drawn between buttons.

How can I add arrows to one end of my lines?

It would like like this when complete.

[image]

thanks
JN

Comment: Can you show me screenshot how it will look after add arrow ?

Comment: I added an image of what I want the final view to look like.  You can see how the arrows point in from each outer button to the center button.

Answer (score 0):

I found two way for achieve your requirement.

1) To use nine patch image. I have tried to make **nine patch image** for you please use it [image]

2) You can use **vector image** for it.

Tell me still you not getting solution.